# Error in database connection

Tags: wp-config

I am using Wamp server, I want to develop website using WordPress. I have configured wp-config.php. Still it is showing me

> Error establishing a database connection.

How should I solve this error?

Comment: Are you sure the hostname, database name, database username and password are correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try deleting `wp-config.php` or rename it, then go to your site, then follow the setup instructions.

by deleting `wp-config.php` it will make your site run setup wizard when you visit your home page. It will ask you your database configuration. And if you fill out each input fields with correct data, then your site is good to go.

Otherwise, your problem lies on your database host.

Comment: This isn't an answer but a comment. To make this useful as an answer, please [edit](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/145321/edit) your answer and properly explain what needs to be done during setup

Comment: @PieterGoosen I understand you well, but before I submitted this as an answer, I have a 50-50 thoughts that this **is** a comment. But then, has a high chance that the problem of the OP will be solved with this, so I put it as answer.

Comment: Please explain _why_ this answer is helpful.

Comment: @kaiser, there I tried my best.

Comment: I have tried this. I think the Username and Password is mismatched/wrong. Thank you for your answer.